# Reformat Strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, reformatting

How can I reformat this string

```
0 - 32 1994--245
```

To

```
032-199-42-45
```

I Tried this but my output is wrong

```
['0 - 32 1994--245'].replace(/[- ]/g, '')
.match(/(\d{1,3})/g)
.join('-')
```

my output is

```
 032-199-424-5
```

Comment: Is the number of digits in the string always the same? Can there be a `0 - 32 1994--245 -456` input? If yes, what is the expected output?

Comment: I assume the answer to above is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove all non digits and group by three or two digits.

```js
var string = '0 - 32 1994--245',
    result = string
        .replace(/\D+/g, '')
        .match(/.{2,3}(?=..)|.+/g)
        .join('-');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

```js
var str = '0 - 32 1994--245'.replace(/[- ]/g, '')

console.log(str.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4'))
```

**Demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/xnCL8K/1